# Transpose a word written vertically to horizontally in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transpose

I want to use T-SQL to transpose a column with a word, such as

```
t
r
a
i
n
```

into

```
train
```

I tried using pivot, but instead of getting only one row back with the transposed column, I got a 5x5 table showing 'train' along the diagonal, and NULL everywhere else. This result makes sense to me, but it's not what I want. I just want to transpose a word written vertically into the same word but written horizontally. How should I approach this with pivot? Or is there an easier way to do it otherwise?

Conversely, if I had instead started out with a word

```
train
```

how would I transpose this word to make it print vertically?

```
t
r
a
i
n
```

Thank you!

Comment: What RDMS are you using? I deleted my answer because it was SQL Server specific and you only tagged [sql].

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Whichever answer you go with for the first part of this question, please think about the query which returns one letter on each row...The solution is dependent upon the order. So if you use it in a *real* scenario, make sure you have an `order by` clause in the query which returns the letters; otherwise at some point in future, SQL might decide a different access path, returning your letters in a different order.

Comment: SQL Server 2017 has a function [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which is worth looking into if you're up to date with versions.

Comment: Is this a homework question? There would never be a valid real life scenario for this...

Comment: I saw it when I was looking up types of SQL interview questions and became curious as to how it was done.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can try to use CTE recursive

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   col varchar(50)
);

insert into t values ('train');

;with cte as (
  select 
         1 startIdx,
         len(col) maxlenght,
         col
  from t
  UNION ALL
  select 
         startIdx+1, 
         maxlenght,
         col
  from cte
  where startIdx + 1 <= maxlenght
)

select substring(col,startIdx,1),col
from cte
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a68be48930cd6660420dc68df751ae80)

**Result**

```
t
r
a
i
n
```

---

If you want to let char to tranpose a column with a word, you can try to use `FOR XML`

```
create TABLE T2  (c NVARCHAR(1))
INSERT T2 VALUES('t'),('r'),('a'),('i'),('n');

SELECT STUFF((SELECT c FROM T2 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'')
```

[sqfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f61821639f6f28583bd1e6a90b2f7d6f)

**RESULT**

```
train
```

Comment: @kkun Is that word for you?

Comment: No need for `STUFF()` here... This is only needed in cases, where you add a delimiter, which must be removed to avoid it at the string's beginning.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach :

```
DECLARE 
    @t TABLE(word VARCHAR(50) ) 
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('t'),
('r'),
('a'),
('i'),
('n')


SELECT (SELECT word FROM @t FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
```

Comment: Not the best advise... At least not as a general *how to* approach... If there was a character in the input, which needs escaping, you'll get it back unescaped. Try this with an `&` in the input.

Comment: @Shnugo  I've fixed it the special character case, thanks for noting that.

Comment: oh no... Did you try this? What about `<` and many more? See my answer for a general approach

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #a (word varchar(1)

insert into #a values('T'),('R'),('A'),('I'),('N')

declare @a varchar (10)=''
select @a=@a+ word  from #a
select @a
```

Comment: The *quirky update*  (`SELECT @v=@v + ...`) is nothing to recommend to new-comers... [This article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) explains the backgrounds... Might be the fastest, but has some dangerous traps...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do the first one, especially if you need to be able to group by an account number or other columns. I also included a commented out way to do the letters as comma separated in case that's a potential need. I've used that to display all service codes on an account.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Account BIGINT NOT NULL,
    Value NVARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @t
(Account,Value)
VALUES
(1,'t'),(1,'r'),(1,'a'),(1,'i'),(1,'n'),
(2,'c'),(2,'a'),(2,'t');

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
    a.Account,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(v.Value,'<Value>',''),'</Value>','') AS Value
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.Account
    FROM @t AS t
) AS a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT v.Value
    FROM @t AS v
    WHERE v.Account = a.Account
    ORDER BY v.Id
    FOR XML PATH ('')
) AS v (Value);

/*
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.Account
    FROM @t AS t
) AS a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v.Id)
            WHEN 1 THEN ''
            ELSE ', '
        END + (v.Value)
    FROM @t AS v
    WHERE v.Account = a.Account
    ORDER BY v.Id
    FOR XML PATH ('')
) AS v (Value);
*/

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Comment: Not the best advise... At least not as a general *how to* approach... If there was a character in the input, which needs escaping, you'll get it back unescaped. Try this with an `&` in the input.

Comment: You're correct on those characters. I was going based on the requirement of "transpose a column with a word". Not as dynamic as a column with any character, but there ya go. That STRING_AGG function is pretty cool though. Didn't know about that. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers already, most of them working for this tiny case, but all of them not unproblematic:

- The *quirky update* has [side-effects](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) one should really deeply know about
- All XML-approaches get in troubles with escaped characters like `& -> &amp;`
- All approaches might get in troubles with larger strings, when there is no explicit sort order and the engine decides to go in parallel mode

Here are two secure approaches to get single characters and two secure approaches to get the strings back. Try it out:

```
DECLARE @Word1 NVARCHAR(100)='train';
DECLARE @Word2 NVARCHAR(100)='this & that'; --the "&" can lead to troubles in XML

DECLARE @singleChars TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,WordId INT,Chr CHAR(1));
```

--Tally (a set of running numbers)
--Best was an existing (physical) numbers table, but this shows the principles

```
WITH tally(nmbr) AS (SELECT TOP(LEN(@Word1)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) --the "FROM master..spt_values" is just to pick a table with a high number of rows... We do not need the values, just the set...
INSERT INTO @singleChars(WordId,Chr)
SELECT 1,SUBSTRING(@Word1,nmbr,1)
FROM tally;
```

--recursive
--This is a *hidden RBAR* approach (rather *iterativ* than *recursive*)

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ChrPos,SUBSTRING(@Word2,1,1) AS Chr
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.ChrPos +1, SUBSTRING(@Word2,cte.ChrPos+1,1)
    FROM cte 
    WHERE cte.ChrPos+1<=LEN(@Word2)
)
INSERT INTO @singleChars(WordId,Chr)
SELECT 2,Chr
FROM cte
ORDER BY ChrPos;
```

--check the result

```
SELECT * FROM @singleChars;
```

--Now we re-concatenate the single characters.
--XML approach

```
SELECT (SELECT sc1.Chr 
        FROM @singleChars sc1
        WHERE sc.WordId=sc1.WordId
        ORDER BY ID --never forget the "ORDER BY"!
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(100)') --read with `.value()` to ensure re-escaping
FROM @singleChars sc
GROUP BY WordId;
```

--STRING_AGG(needs v2017+)

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(sc.Chr,NULL) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ID) --again the "ORDER BY"!
FROM @singleChars sc
GROUP BY WordId
```